# PHPUnit 10 specify different method arguments on consecutive calls to the same method

Tags: php, phpunit, phpunit-10

I have a method that's called several times with different arguments as part of a larger method.

```
$query->where("one", $id);
$query->where("two", "LIKE %{$name}%");
$query->where("three", false);
$query->where("four", true);
```

I'm using PHPUnit 10 and I want to write a unit test for this particular method. I want to check if the `where` method is called 4 times with some specific arguments.

For example:

```
$mockedQuery->expects($this->exactly(4))
->method("where")
->with(
// Here I'd like to specify the list of arguments
// or perhaps a map or something
)
->willReturn($mockedQuery);
```

The above `->will` does not work for specifying different arguments for consecutive calls on the same method(or at least I can't get it to work).

I've tried using the documentation but not knowing what to search for exactly makes it hard to find.

Answer (score 0):

I'll answer my own question since I had to do some digging.

For PHPUnit 10 the method `withConsecutive`(which was what I was looking for, I just didn't know it was called that) was removed. No official replacement exists.

[The issue was raised on the PHPUnit repo](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/issues/4026)

The workaround I used was

```
$matcher = $this->exactly(2);
$this->mock
    ->expects($matcher)
    ->method('get')
    ->willReturnCallback(function (string $param) use ($matcher) {
                match ($matcher->numberOfInvocations()) {
                    1 => $this->assertEquals($param, 'someValue'),
                    2 => $this->assertEquals($param, 'someOtherValue'),
                };
            })
```